# How to find Conflicts in merge request before create

Tags: git, git-flow, merge-conflict-resolution

How to find git conflicts Before creating merge request?
I want to find conflicts before create merge request and push that. if I test merge and not conflict exit branches merged and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to merge the base branch into your feature branch (or viceversa) to see if there are conflicts:

```
git fetch origin
git merge --no-commit origin/the-base-branch
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo there are conflicts
fi
```